# Why audio fail after cutting one wire off ear-bud pair with 3.5mm TRS audio jack

Tags: audio

I have an iroger hearing mono amplifier to help me hear better.  It came with a 3.5mm TRRS jack two-wire earbud pair.  The mic has 3.5mm TS jack.  I want to just use the left bud so I want to cut off the right bud to avoid the right one dangling and tangling.  Before I do that, as a test I cut the right bud wire off a different known-good bud pair that has a 3.5mm TRS jack.  It worked on my iroger before cutting but does not work on my iroger after cutting.  But the now-single-bud does indeed work on my computer 3.5mm jack.  A different 3.5mm TRS ear bud pair does indeed work on the iroger.  I'm confused as to why my now-single 3.5mm TRS bud does not work on my iroger.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Which wire you cut? We can't know if you cut the correct wire and what your device expects from the headphones to detect them properly. It might try to detect if the other now missing driver is present or it may require both drivers to be present.

Comment: The buds are marked L and R.  I cut the R wire.

Comment: do you mean R cable, or do you mean R wire inside the cable?

Comment: From the 3.5mm TRS jack there are two cables (stuck together).  I cut the cable (and the one-and-only wire inside it) that goes to the bud marked R.  I do not how many wires inside the other cable.

Comment: That's not true. There must be two conductors inside the cable. It will not work with only one conductor. If you simply chopped it off, it may short circuit the signal wire to ground wire. If the device has single mono output driving both buds, then the chopped off wire can short the left signal too. Please don't simply chop off stuff and let conductors get short circuited together.

Comment: You're right! There are two wires in the single R cable. One looked like just string to reinforce the rubber cable but under magnification it does looks like copper.  But where I cut, they are not touching and all was off when I made the cut.  Does the L cable also have two wires?  (My ohm-meter does not indicate that either of these two fine wires are conductive.  I get infinity when touching the two probes but zero when touching a short piece of either wire.)

Comment: Sorry, Correction:  I don't get "infinity." I get "zero" when touching across the two ohm-meter probes or a thicker wire or a paper clip.   I get "1" when touching a short length of either of the two bud wirew, indicating (to me) non-conducting.   But anyway, the now-single earbud does indeed work on my computer audio, just not on the iroger, and other ear buds do indeed work on the iroger.

Comment: I tried cutting one wire of the pair on another earbud set with the same result.  Works on my my computer and laptop but not the amplifier.  Then I bought a cheap single-wire earbud (3.5mm TS) and it works on all.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your hearing amplifier connects to the earbuds in such a way that they are in series. When you chop off one of the earbuds, you remove part of the circuit, so the remaining one has no return path.

Most stereo headphones are wired like this:

Tip-----[L driver]------Sleeve------[R driver]---- Ring,

so if you feed a signal to tip and ring (while ignoring sleeve, not connecting anything to it) both drivers will be in series.

A mono headphone connector only has Tip and Sleeve, the sleeve being a single piece as long as sleeve and ring together would be on a stereo plug.

All your experiments would behave exactly like you describe if the female connector on your device contacts only the tip and the ring. (Since it would be expecting this position to be part of the sleeve of a mono connector)

Here I've drawn a crude comparison between a stereo headphone and a mono earbud:

[image]

Your computer most likely has a stereo output which is nothing but two output channels where the sleeve is common to both drivers, so when you cut one bud off, that channel just "sees" an open circuit, but the other one "sees" no change.

If you test a complete headphone pair with your multimeter in resistance mode, you should get a value between sleeve and ring, and (almost) the same value between sleeve and tip. Now if you measure between tip and ring, the value should be close to the double of before. Also, you should get continuity between tip and ring.

If you repeat these with the chopped off headphone, you should get a value between tip and sleeve, but infinite between ring and sleeve and infinite between tip and ring.

Comment: I did your experiment and it is as you describe.  Some weeks ago I bought a single ear bud with a 3.5mm TS jack (monaural obviously) and it works.  The microphone also has a 3.5mm TS jack.  I'm all set.  Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

The wires inside are very fine, delicate, and close together. If you just lop it off, chances are wires on the cut end are shorted together.